# What steps are required to migrate Asterisk from PRI to SIP trunk?

Tags: asterisk, sip, asteriskami

We are planing to migrate our asterisk servers from PRi to SIP Trunk. First I need to configure on test AWS instance.

Answer (score -1):

You just need setup sip trunk acordinly to info your provider give.

Thats all. In most case even no need in change dialplan.

If you want it get on other box, you have setup box. Alot of articles already writed about that, for aws too.

Comment: Thanks.. and also please share me reference link for AWS

Comment: Common. Google know alot of links about that, even video on youtube. It is not something very special.